# Merging HttpHandler return Observable with another in HttpInterceptor (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, observable, angular-http-interceptors

We're running Angular 8.  Our API is setup so that the body of the response includes a "data" attribute and an "errors" attribute.  They aren't mutually exclusive - there can be data AND errors in the response and we want both.  We're successful in setting the Observable next event to emit the nested data response.  However, this ignores the errors.  We would like to process the errors on the calling component by subscribing in the following way

`this.myService.getData.subscribe(resp => {...}, error => {...});`

This is our interceptor code:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(map((event) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

      if (event.body && event.body.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
        const eventClone = event.clone({ body: event.body['data'] });
        return eventClone;
      }

      return event;
    }
  }));
```

}

I've tried concatenating two observables, modifying the current one, and other approaches but am ultimately not successful in getting both the errors and response back to the component.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work with the following code.  There could very well be a better way of doing this, but this is what ended up working:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof HttpResponse),
    switchMap(res => {
      let httpResponse: HttpResponse<any> = res as HttpResponse<any>;
      let formattedResponse = httpResponse.clone({ body: httpResponse.body['data'] })
      if (res['body'] && res['body']['errors']) {
        let errors = res['body']['errors'];
        return new Observable<HttpResponse<any>>(o => {
          o.next(formattedResponse);
          o.error(errors)
        });
      } else return new Observable<HttpResponse<any>>(o => o.next((formattedResponse)));
    }));
```

}